# Why is Rails running in development mode during rake test task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Why is the following Rake task being run in Rails' development environment?

```
namespace :app_tests do
  desc "Run unit tests."
  task unit: [:environment] do
    RAILS_ENV = "test"
    Rails.env = "test"
    system "rake test RAILS_ENV=test"
  end
end
```

I was running into `require` errors caused by missing (test group) dependencies and it turns out that's because `app_tests:unit` is being run in Rails' development environment when run using `bundle exec rake app_tests:unit`.

How can I *force* this task to run in Rails' test environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development environmnet is run by default, you need to declare the testing environment explicitly

`RAILS_ENV=test rake app_tests:unit`

You can enforce the env var in your task specifically by doing something like what they did with `rspec/core` [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake#L23)

Comment: Removing the `:environment` dependency (which was loading the problematic initializer using the development environment) and explicitly setting the environment using the Rspec example (`Rails.env = ENV["RACK_ENV"] = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"`) solved my problem.